# RSpec system tests: Reset Password Token is invalid

Tags: rspec, devise, capybara

I've been banging my head against this one for the past 90 minutes.

I have a Ruby on Rails application using:

```rb
gem 'rails', '~> 7.1.2'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.9'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 6.1.0'
gem 'capybara', '~> 3.39'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 4.16'
```

I just cannot get my system specs to pass for the "Reset Password" function of Devise. They keep failing because I'm getting `Reset Password Token is invalid`. Do note that the process works perfectly if done manually on my Development environment.

Here's my spec:

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Password Reset', type: :system do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  it 'allows a user to recover their password' do
    visit new_user_password_path

    fill_in User.human_attribute_name(:email), with: user.email
    click_button I18n.t('devise.passwords.send_email_cta_button')

    expect(page).to have_content(I18n.t('devise.passwords.send_instructions'))
    expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count).to eq(1)

    email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
    html = Nokogiri::HTML(email.body.to_s)
    target_url = html.at("a:contains('#{I18n.t('devise.passwords.email.link_cta')}')")['href']

    visit target_url

    fill_in I18n.t('devise.passwords.new_password'), with: 'new_password'
    fill_in I18n.t('devise.passwords.new_password_confirmation'), with: 'new_password'
    click_button I18n.t('devise.passwords.update_cta')

    expect(page).to have_content(I18n.t('devise.passwords.updated'))
  end
end
```

I've also tried just navigating to the edit_password_path by grabbing the token from the User record, and also reloading the record before I do it. I've also tried to set the hidden `user_reset_password_token` form field manually to match the token currently in the database... all to no avail.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?